# Percentage change using two columns, one shifted

Tags: python, dataframe, vectorization, percentage

I have a dataframe that contains the following columns:

```
member (float64), datetime (datetime64[ns]), var1(float64), var2(float64)
```

How can I calculate percentage change between each element of var1 and 1-step lagged var2, doing this by each member? The result should be created as a new column.

```
    var1     var2  member      datetime       expected new column
   131.255  137.032  1   2017-02-02 09:15:00   n/a
   129.700  131.193  1   2017-02-02 09:20:00  -0.05351 ((129.7-137.032)/137.032)
```

New column would then start with `var1[1]-var2[0]/var2[0]` per "member".
The only way I tried is to create two pivot tables and calculate the difference per-element, but I think there should be a more efficient way using vectorization?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added. I think I should use vectorization via lambda, but could not succeed trying this.

Comment: sorry, added now. will improve my questions and state them more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort the data so that rows belonging to the same member are next to each other.

```
df = df.sort_values(['member', 'datetime'])
```

create an array of shifted var2 for each group of member

```
shifted = df.groupby('member').var2.shift() # the default shifts by 1, which is needed here
```

assign a new column using the shifted array for calculation

```
df['newcol'] = (df.var1 - shifted) / shifted
```

This adds the extra column

```
      var1     var2  member             datetime    newcol
0  131.255  137.032       1  2017-02-02 09:15:00       NaN
1  129.700  131.193       1  2017-02-02 09:20:00 -0.053506
```

or, do it in 1 line:

```
df['newcol'] = df.var1/df.groupby('member').var2.shift()-1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['ratio'] = (df['var1'] / df['var2'].shift()) - 1

print(df)

      var1     var2  member     ratio
0  131.255  137.032       1       NaN
1  129.700  131.193       1 -0.053506
```

If you require a per-member calculation, you need to provide a larger sample of your data and show us exactly your desired output for a larger dataset.